# C++ how to flush stdin

Tags: c++, stdin

I have a program where a client is in receiving mode and it's waiting to receive some data; while the program is "blocked" if the user write on the terminal, when the program come back from the receiving i have a `std::getline()` that has to read from the stdin but it read the input given by the user when the program was blocked instead to give me the opportunity to do a `std::cin`.

How can I flush all the input provide by the user when the program was blocked on receiving the data?

That's the pseudocode:

```
{
    ...
    int ret = receive(socket,buffer,0);
    //During the receive the program will be blocked on the receive till it will be completed 
    
    //If the user type something in the stdin before the receive above it's completede when the getline it's executed it catch the bad input given by the user when the receive is processing

    getline(cin, buffer);

    
    ...

}
```

Comment: You will need to use non-blocking I/O to read any buffered data on standard input. This is outside the scope of the C++ standard, and you will need to use your operating system-specific facilities to do that.

Comment: I edited the question, i don't know if now it's clearer

Comment: There is no way to flush `stdin`. Trying to do so is undefined behaviour. You should not attempt to implement this functionality anyway, lest you want your users to become very angry at you. If I type something to a program, the very last thing I expect from it is to throw away my input because it was "busy".

Comment: I'm totally agree with you but this things written when the program it's busy may be an attack from a malicious user so I need to ignore it in some way. That's for security reasons.

Comment: "_That's the pseudocode_" - Now try the real code.

Comment: You _flush_ the writing side, not the reading side.

Comment: I agree with @SamVarshavchik. It is not possible in ISO C++. It can only be accomplished using OS-specific features. Therefore, if you want an answer to your question, you will have to change your question to how to accomplish the task on a specific operating system.

Comment: "may be an attack from a malicious user so I need to ignore it in some way". That doesn't really make a lot of sense. A user can type the exact same thing when the program is not busy. The program need not and should not know exactly when on the axis of time each individual character was typed. You filter out malicious input by looking at its content, not its timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a so called Reactor. There is a design pattern for that. You want to wait for an event from 2 or more sources.

To solve this, you can use one of the many existing functions like `select` or `poll` or `epoll`.

With this functions you can register a desired event on a certain handle (like a socket, or a file handle, or cin (which is in this sense nothing but a handle)) with your operating system.

As soon as your specified event happens on the dedicated handle, the functions will return and indicate where what happend. Then you can decide what to do.

There are also versions of those functions with a timeout.

So, you shift the "blocking" from 2 functions `receive` or `getline` to one function like `epoll`.

If you do not want to have blocking at all, but rather asynchronious handling, then you could use the Proactor pattern with a completion handler. That is mostly used in high speed server applications.

But nowadays you can also easily use multi threaded functions using `std::async` and a cheap `future`

That should solve your problem.